# CountDownTimer not accurate

Tags: android, android-service

I have an Android service running in the background.
I want to be notified after a specific period of time (22 seconds), so I wrote:

```
private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(22*1000,22*1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {}

    public void onFinish() {
        doSomething();
    }
};
```

I run this, and get the notification after 40 seconds, and even 50 seconds. Am I doing something wrong? How can this be done?

Comment: Have you tried playing around with the (second) input(s)?
Maybe this helps: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html
 And where do you start your countdown?

Comment: don't set countDownInterval the same as millisInFuture. Set it to 1000 ms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually  you are putting interval time as wll 22000, what this you are doing wrong. Second parameter is the interval.So , Do this :

CountDownTimer alertTimer = new CountDownTimer(22*1000, 1000) {

```
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            // Do here what you want


        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

        }
    }.start();
```

Comment: I don't see any problem with interval equals the timeout of the countdown, But I will try it.

Comment: What interval does it will decrement or increment after that amount of interval that is if you put 2000ms then the timer each time will increment after 2 second by one.it will effect definately